# Javascript Array logging confusion

Tags: javascript, arrays, console

I have noticed something that I cannot understand at all. I am doing something really simple in JavaScript:

```
var a = [1,2,3];

console.log(a.push(4));
console.log(a);
console.log(a.push(5));
```

I would expect the console to log: `4`, `[1,2,3,4]`, and `5` as described **[here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push)** for example. 
The catch is that the actual console output looks like: `4`, `[1,2,3,4,5]`, and `5`

See: http://jsfiddle.net/HknMF/

What on earth makes the `5` appear in the second log output?

*EDIT*: fwiw here's a screenshot of Firebug showing both behaviors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/x2XH8.png

​

Comment: are you sure? I tried running your code in jsfiddle and the console output is as expected... I am on Firefox 10.0.2. What browser are you using?

Comment: @Hery yes I am sure, I tried it in Chrome & Firefox (with Firebug). What kind of console are you using? Firebug too?

Comment: @Hery strangely enough I can get Firebug to show both behaviors. The "odd" one will display a `HknMF/show` as source, the other one states `_display`

Comment: Very weird indeed. For me, both HknMF/show and _display show the same output. I tried running the jsfiddle code in chromium though, and I finally get to see your output...

Comment: @Hery I added a screenshot, very weird....

Comment: Hahaha very strange... Here is mine http://i.imgur.com/KDXl4.png

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The console in some browsers uses a reference to the array/object, so when you inspect it and the object changed after the `console.log()` call you'll see the changed object.

In Firefox this also happens for objects, but not for arrays which are displayed inline anyway:

```
>>> var a = [1,2,3]; console.log(a.push(4)); console.log(a); console.log(a.push(5));
4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
5
```

Especially for objects that do not contain functions a quick workaround is either cloning them (log `$.extend({}, yourObject)` if you have jQuery) or logging their JSON string version (then you lose the nice object view and just get a plain string though). An array can easily cloned (shallow copy!) using `a.slice(0)`

Comment: Ok that explains a lot, is there a way to log the current state of an Array?

Comment: `JSON.stringify()` or clone it (`a.slice(0)`)

Comment: ...or `console.log(a + ''); console.log(a.join(','));`

Answer (score 1):

Dependent of the Browser either your live array gets logged (Chrome) or A string representation (Firefox).

A shallow copy is sufficient to prevent that. Use:

```
console.log( a.slice(0) );
```

for that.