# Array length is 0 even though it has items

Tags: typescript

I have an array where I have pushed in objects from a rest call. When I console log the array it has items, but when I check with length it says 0.
I've googled for a bit, but can't seem to find a solution. This is my console:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
private getArkiv(): void {
    const currentUser = this.context.pageContext.user.email
    const requestUrl = `https://johannawl.sharepoint.com/sites/Maintainance/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Arkivlista')/items?$select=ID,libGuid,PageType,Site,Owner/Title,Owner/EMail&$expand=Owner&$filter=Owner/EMail%20eq%20%27${currentUser}%27%20and%20PageType%20eq%20%27Scenkonst%27`
    let siteUrl: string;
    let LibGuid: string;
    const fileArr: {FileLeafRef: string; href: string; Id: string; isArchived: boolean;}[] = [];
    
    this.getItemsRest(requestUrl).then(data => {

      for (let i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
        const item = data.value[i];
        siteUrl = item.Site.Url;
        LibGuid = item.libGuid;
        const requestUri = `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbyid('${LibGuid}')/items?$select=Title,ID,FileRef,FileLeafRef,attention&$filter=attention%20eq%20%271%27`

        this.getFilesRest(requestUri).then(data => {
          for (let j = 0; j < data.value.length; j++) { 
            const fileItem = data.value[j];
            const file = this.addFile(fileItem);
            fileArr.push(file);
            console.log('jw fileItem: ', fileItem)
          }
        })
      }

      this.processData(fileArr)
      console.log("jw fileArr: ", fileArr);
      console.log("jw length fileArr: ", fileArr.length);
      console.log("jw is array fileArr: ", Array.isArray(fileArr));
    })
  }

private processData(data: any): void {
    let html: string = "";
    let count: number = 0;
    let countst: string = "";
    for (let i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
      const file = data[i];
      html += `
      <tr>
        <td>
          <span><a href="${file.href}">${file.FileLeafRef}</a></span>
        </td>
        <td>
          <span>Test</span>
        </td>
      </tr>
      `;
      count++;
      countst = count.toString();
    }
    $("#Alla").text(`Filer (${countst})`);
    document.getElementById("tbodyAlla").innerHTML = html;
    $("#table").DataTable({
      responsive: true,
      destroy: true
    })
  }
```

Comment: By the time you do `console.log` there's no elements in array because your asyncronous call `getFilesRest` haven't finished it's work.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Javascript Array logging confusion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734487/javascript-array-logging-confusion)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

At the point `console.log("jw fileArr: ", fileArr);` run, `fileArr` is actually still empty because the promise have not been resolved yet. It appears containing item because ***the console evaluate the value of an logged object/array when you expand it.*** By the time you expand the array in the console, the promise has been resolved so it appears to have items.

You should run whatever you want to do after the request finished inside the then block (or subsequent then blocks). You can use [Promise.all](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) to wait for all requests as a whole.

```
    this.getItemsRest(requestUrl).then(data => {

      let promises = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < data.value.length; i++) {
        const item = data.value[i];
        siteUrl = item.Site.Url;
        LibGuid = item.libGuid;
        const requestUri = `${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbyid('${LibGuid}')/items?$select=Title,ID,FileRef,FileLeafRef,attention&$filter=attention%20eq%20%271%27`

        promises.push(this.getFilesRest(requestUri));
      }
      Promise.all(promises).then(dataArr => {
        for (let data of dataArr) {
          for (let fileItem of data.value) {
            const file = this.addFile(fileItem);
            fileArr.push(file);
            console.log('jw fileItem: ', fileItem)
          }
        }
        this.processData(fileArr)
        console.log("jw fileArr: ", fileArr);
        console.log("jw length fileArr: ", fileArr.length);
        console.log("jw is array fileArr: ", Array.isArray(fileArr));
      })
    })
```

Also consider using `async-await` syntax to replace promise, which makes the code more easily understandable. The code can also be further simplified with `for-of` loop, `map` and `flatMap`.

```
  private async getArkiv(): Promise<void> {
    const currentUser = this.context.pageContext.user.email;
    const requestUrl = `https://johannawl.sharepoint.com/sites/Maintainance/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('Arkivlista')/items?$select=ID,libGuid,PageType,Site,Owner/Title,Owner/EMail&$expand=Owner&$filter=Owner/EMail%20eq%20%27${currentUser}%27%20and%20PageType%20eq%20%27Scenkonst%27`;
    
    const data = await this.getItemsRest(requestUrl);
    const promises = data.map({libGuid,Site:{Url:siteUrl}} => this.getFilesRest(`${siteUrl}/_api/web/lists/getbyid('${libGuid}')/items?$select=Title,ID,FileRef,FileLeafRef,attention&$filter=attention%20eq%20%271%27`));

    const dataArr = await Promise.all(promises);
    const fileArr: { 
      FileLeafRef: string; 
      href: string; 
      Id: string; 
      isArchived: boolean; 
    }[] = dataArr.flatMap(it => it.value);
    
    for(let fileItem of fileArr){
      this.addFile(fileItem);
    }

    this.processData(fileArr);
    console.log("jw fileArr: ", fileArr);
    console.log("jw length fileArr: ", fileArr.length);
    console.log("jw is array fileArr: ", Array.isArray(fileArr));
  }
```

Comment: I have done that. The problem is that I have a list with different sites and libraries (the first call). I have to loop through that listitem so I can fetch the files. So now when I hit refresh I'll get the two from one library, then hit refresh again and get 1 from the other library.

Comment: @JohannaWeidenius Sorry didn't notice there is a for loop. updated the answer.